# mongoose: Populating a discriminated subdocument

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-populate, discriminator

I want to populate the fields of a subdocument, which is a discriminated element of a common Schema (`Notificationable` discriminated into `Message` or `FriendRequest`).

This question is quite similar to this one: [mongoosejs: populating an array of objectId's from different schemas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34101130/mongoosejs-populating-an-array-of-objectids-from-different-schemas), which was not solved two years ago. Since mongoose evolved, and discriminator also, I am asking the question again.

What I have tried so far:

```
Notification.find({_id: 'whatever'})
    .populate({
        path: 'payload',
        match: {type: 'Message'},
        populate: ['author', 'messageThread']
    })
    .populate({
        path: 'payload',
        match: {type: 'FriendRequest'},
        populate: ['to', 'from']
    })
    .exec();
```

This does not work, because the path is the same. 
So I tried:

```
Notification.find({_id: 'whatever'})
    .populate({
        path: 'payload',
        populate: [
            {
                path: 'messageThread',
                match: {type: 'Message'},
            },
            {
                path: 'author',
                match: {type: 'Message'},
            },
            {
                path: 'from',
                match: {type: 'FriendRequest'},
            },
            {
                path: 'to',
                match: {type: 'FriendRequest'},
            },

        ]
    })
    .exec();
```

Which does not work either, maybe because the match is executed in the subdocument and thus does not have a field `type`.

Is there any solution for this?

---

Here are my (main) models, I did not provide User or MessageThread.

**The main document:**

```
const NotificationSchema = new Schema({
    title: String,
    payload: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Notificationable'
    });
mongoose.model('Notification', NotificationSchema);
```

**The payload Parent schema**

```
let NotificationableSchema = new Schema(
    {},
    {discriminatorKey: 'type', timestamps: true}
);
mongoose.model('Notificationable', NotificationableSchema);
```

And the two discriminated possibilities:

```
let Message = new Schema({
    author: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User'
    },
    messageThread: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, 
        ref: 'MessageThread'
    }
}
Notificationable.discriminator('Message', Message);
```

And:

```
let FriendRequest = new Schema({
    from: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User'
    },
    to: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User'
    }
}
Notificationable.discriminator('FriendRequest', FriendRequest);
```

Comment: For someone using the mongoose-autopopulate plugin, it "is based entirely on pre('find') and pre('findOne') hooks, which don't get fired for the child model when you do find() on the parent model."  reference: https://github.com/mongodb-js/mongoose-autopopulate/issues/26